# Dealing with floating points/decimals in PHP

Tags: php, rounding, currency

I'm building a web application that is handling some money/prices that may change from time to time. To facilitate this, I have a `config.php` which is required and includes some definitions:

`define('PRODUCT_PRICE', 2000.00);`

`define('PRODUCT_PRICE_WITH_GST', PRODUCT_PRICE * 1.1);`

When it comes time for the prospect to enter the checkout process, I display the price as follows:

`<?php echo(PRODUCT_PRICE_WITH_GST); ?>`

I was expecting this to print as `2200.00` but rather it's dropping off the decimal points and displaying as `2200`.

What's the best practice way to handle this?

Comment: Do you mean `2200` instead of `2200.00`? Or `2000` instead of `2200.00`?

Comment: 2220 - my bad. Edited question to reflect actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use number_format: http://php.net/number_format

if you var_dump() your constant, you see its internal representation is a double, it is only a manner of how you show it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the functions [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) and [printf](http://php.net/printf) for various kinds of string formatting. Your particular problem has the following solution:

```
printf("%01.2f", PRODUCT_PRICE_WITH_GST);
```

Comment: Thanks Sharanya. I'm testing that now and that seems to return nothing.

Comment: Replace the entire line `echo(PRODUCT_PRICE_WITH_GST);` with the line I’ve suggested. Is it working?

Comment: Alternatively, you may go for `echo(sprintf("%01.2f", PRODUCT_PRICE_WITH_GST));` though some may consider it bad practice to use `echo` in conjunction with `sprintf` instead of just `printf`.

Comment: I can't see how this could be the problem. The OP is talking of no rounding error on printing - it is missing a full 10% of the integer value - "2000" instead of "2200"

Comment: @jsbueno Allow me to quote from the question (with italics added for emphasis): “I was expecting this to print as `2200.00` but rather _it's dropping off the decimal points_ and displaying as `2000`.” It seems to me that `2000` is nothing but a typographical error.

Comment: Indeed - I think the OP just made a typo in the question - sorry. Number formatting is the way to go them.